# Accumulate rows in SQL: summarizing previous values and new grouped by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

In SQL Server 2008, If I have a table like this.

```
Date          NoOfCases
--------------------
2013-11-27    1
2013-11-28    2
2013-11-29    1
2013-11-30    3
```

And I want the previous sum to be added to the next row's value. That means that the output should be like this:

```
Date          AccumulatedNoOfCases
2013-11-27    1
2013-11-28    3
2013-11-29    4
2013-11-30    7
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a join on same table, with the date being smaller or equal.

```
select t1.date, sum(t2.NoOfCases) as AccumulatedNoOfCases
from Table1 t1
join Table1 t2 on t2.Date <= t1.Date
group by t1.date
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a30c/10)

With count, i would use a cte for simplicity

```
with cnt as (select date, count(*) as cnt from Table1
             group by date)

select t1.date, sum(t2.cnt) as AccumulateNoOfCases
FROM cnt t1
join cnt t2 on t2.date <=t1.date
group by t1.date;
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6174e/2)

With your datas, it should be something like that.

```
WITH cte as
(select [Date of hospital visit]) as dte, count(*) as cnt
 FROM DW_Epidemic_Warning
 GROUP BY [Date of hospital visit])

select t1.dte, sum(t2.cnt) as AccumulateNoOfCases
FROM cte t1
join cte t2 on t2.dte <=t1.dte
group by t1.dte;
```

Comment: That works for the case I presented. Thanks. Do you know how to do it if I have to first make a count of the rows to get NoOfCases? I would like to make a COUNT within the sum or something.

Comment: well, use a subquery ?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying that, but I just keep getting the total COUNT of the rows. I.e. if there are 30 rows it just adds 30+30+30 and so on, when I want the final sum to be 30. Sorry, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say what version of SQL Server you are using.  If it is 2012, you can do something like

```
SELECT 
  t1.date, sum(t1.NoOfCases) OVER (ORDER BY t1.date) AS AccumulatedNoOfCases
FROM Table1 t1
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm using 2008.

Comment: Raphael's approach is the way to go then

Answer (score 0):

I like this one:

```
Select c.CaseDate,
  (Select Sum(NoOfCases) 
   From Cases
   Where CaseDate <= c.CaseDate
   AND CaseDate > '2013-11-20') AS AccumulatedCases
From Cases c
```

Obviously that `AND CaseDate > '2013-11-20'` is completely arbitrary in this case; you'd probably want to use a parameter there.

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/023a4/1)